# SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. Could be an error message instead of a SOAP message

Tags: spring, maven, soap, jboss, saaj

Currently i'm implementing a usecase where i'm supposed to create a soap client which writes over HTTP protocol.
To test the same usecase i have a mock service up and running. Now when i execute the SAAJ implementation of mine as a standalone jar my application works just well and doesn't have any issue.

My problem currently is that when i merge that code in an spring 4 based application and deploy it on Jboss AS 7.1.1, it gives me an error as below :

```
12:40:33,992 ERROR [stderr] (ActiveMQ Session Task-1) com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?

12:40:33,994 ERROR [stderr] (ActiveMQ Session Task-1)   at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(MessageImpl.java:670)

12:40:33,996 ERROR [stderr] (ActiveMQ Session Task-1)   at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:100)

12:40:33,997 ERROR [stderr] (ActiveMQ Session Task-1)   at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:342)

12:40:33,999 ERROR [stderr] (ActiveMQ Session Task-1)   at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:159)
```

Initially i assumed it to be an issue due to other spring dependencies because previously i have struggled with same issues however that isn't the case here, as u can see in pom entries below i removed the conflicting spring -boot-autoconfigure APIS from my war build by making them optional.

my maven dependencies are as below :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.saaj.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>notification</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>notification</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version><!-- 3.0.5.RELEASE 4.1.6.RELEASE -->
        <activemq.version>5.14.3</activemq.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${activemq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>8.4-702.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And my SAAJ implementation is as below :

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLStreamHandler;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConstants;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import com.saaj.client.constants.NotificationConstants;
import com.saaj.client.exception.CustomException;
import com.saaj.client.logger.LoggerManager;

@Component("adapterServiceHelper")
public class AdapterServiceHelper {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerManager.getInstance().getNotificationProcessingLogger();

    public AdapterServiceHelper(){

    }

    public URL getEndpointConnection(String url) throws MalformedURLException, CustomException{
        URL endpoint = null;

        try{
            endpoint = new URL (null, url, new URLStreamHandler () {
                protected URLConnection openConnection (URL url) throws IOException {
                    // The url is the parent of this stream handler, so must create clone
                    URL clone = new URL (url.toString ());
                    URLConnection connection = clone.openConnection ();
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                            "text/xml");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept",
                            "application/soap+xml, text/*");
                    // If we cast to HttpURLConnection, we can set redirects
                    // connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects (false);
                    connection.setConnectTimeout (5 * 1000);      // 15 sec
                    connection.setReadTimeout (5 * 1000);         // 15 sec
                    // Custom header
                    return connection;
                }});


        }catch(MalformedURLException e){
            throw e;
        }catch(Exception exp){
            exp.printStackTrace();
            throw new CustomException(exp.getMessage(),"Error occured while getting endpoint connection to IP");
        }
        return endpoint;
    }

    //main SAAJ implementation
    public SOAPMessage writeCommand(URL endpoint, String command) throws Exception{

        SOAPMessage soapResponse = null;
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        System.out.println("command written is "+command);
        try{
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory
                    .newInstance();
            soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory
                    .createConnection();

            //write to PG over soapConnection can be made generic
            is = new ByteArrayInputStream(command.getBytes());
            SOAPMessage request = MessageFactory.newInstance(
                    SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL).createMessage(
                            new MimeHeaders(), is);

            MimeHeaders headers = request.getMimeHeaders();
            headers.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
            request.saveChanges();


            soapResponse = soapConnection.call(request, endpoint);
            //soapConnection.close();
            //is.close();
            //process soap response
            printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);
        }
        catch(SOAPException exp)
        {
            exp.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("ERROR while connecting SOAP service" + exp.getMessage());
            throw new Exception("ERROR : SOAPException encountered while writing ");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("ERROR : SOAPException encountered while writing ");
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("ERROR : SOAPException encountered while writing ");
        }
        finally{
            soapConnection.close();
            is.close();
        }
        return soapResponse;

    }


    public static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws TransformerException, SOAPException {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                .newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
    }

}
```

Please do let me know if there is any suggestion for this problem.

Comment: Please do let me know if something is wrong with the question I'm asking instead of down voting it. Help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the basic java.net HTTP connection to check what data i'm getting and found that i was really getting the html page for the mock service's port.(localhost:9997)
Say my service is up on the URL : "http://localhost:9997/mockSoapBinding"
So i was getting data for the URL : "http://localhost:9997" instead of the web service exposed.

To check same i used the code below :

```
public String handleRequest(String method, String url, String xmlPayload,String readTimeout,String connectTimeout,String soapAction) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    OutputStreamWriter wr = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String result = "";

    try {
        URL connectionUrl = new URL(url);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) connectionUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod(method);
        if ( xmlPayload != null && ! xmlPayload.equals("")) {
            connection.setReadTimeout(Integer.parseInt(readTimeout));
            connection.setConnectTimeout(Integer.parseInt(connectTimeout));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
            /*connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", soapAction);*/
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(xmlPayload);
            wr.flush();
        }
        try {
            // getInputStream will throw exception when response code is
            // greater than 400, so we need to getErrorStream
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
        }
        StringBuilder bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            bodyBuilder.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        result = String.valueOf( bodyBuilder.toString());
        System.out.println(result);

    } catch(Exception e){
        logger.error("Error occured while send message for : " , e);
            }finally {
        if (wr != null) {
            wr.close();
        }
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if ( connection != null ) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }

    }

    return result;
}
```

Do note this is also an alternative to SAAJ implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message when I provided the wrong namespace in the soap enveloppe. This likely has the same effect as what the accepted answer describes, i.e. the request arrives at the wrong URL.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a dependency issue.

Ok with POI 4.0.1, and fails with 5.0.0, using this pom.xml :

```xml
    </dependencies>
        <!-- @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception -->
        <!-- API, java.xml.bind module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
<!--            <version>5.0.0</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
<!--            <version>5.0.0</version> -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```